# Requests Return blank page after 60 seconds

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Running ColdFusion on IIS every request that runs for more than 60 seconds flushes the browser with a blank page.

Ive tried changing every setting that might affect this and its still happening. I'm out of ideas other than posting here, im not sure if its IIS or ColdFusion timing out.

Comment: And there's nothing in *any* log file? Oh, and which version of CF, and what sort of install (multi-server, stand-alone, etc)

Comment: Which log file, its a standard install, actually an AWS CF AMI

Comment: Well: *any* log file that logs something around when the request fails is gonna have appropriate information in it. Are you only in a position to check one log, so we have to be that precise? ;-) I'd start with the exception.log and application.log. Dunno if AWS CF has -out and -error logs as well?

Comment: Doesnt seem to be anything in any of the logs relating to this. Which makes me suspect something outside of CF. It appears the request continues to run even though the page is flushed.

Comment: I can duplicate it like this
sleep(70000);
writeOutput('Hello World');

Comment: if I do a mail in place of the writeOutput I get the mail, so the cf page is still running

Comment: Are you getting blank pages with all the browsers. Can you enable "developer mode"in the browser (usually F12 is the short key) and see the status code of the request. Also, try decreasing the timeout to 30 seconds in CF Admin for one test request and see if the page throws error. Make sure to enable debugging for this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out, its not IIS or ColdFusion, its the AWS Load Balancer. If I bypass that it works fine.

Comment: Found out that the aws load balancers default to 60 seconds before terminating the connection. You can keep it alive with repeated calls or change your code to be async. You cant change this timeout through the api or control panel. However you can request aws change it for you. The maximum is 17 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, too, it was the load balancer causing the issue, not IIS. Also this resulted in ASP.NET scripts being run twice when the load balancer timed out. It was trying once more to get a result after it timed out the first time. Accessing the scripts via a whitelisted "direct" server IP address avoiding the load balancer fixed the problem.

Also, FYI, the timeouts we were setting manually were effective again, and Response.Flush() started working again. It could well be that beyond the load balancer some caching servers got involved adding to the problem.